# Is it possible to submit set of dynamic pages to Google?

Tags: seo, google-search, dynamic

Suppose that I have a page `example.com/some-page?ending=er` that finds all words that end with given `ending`.

Is it possible to tell Google that this is dynamic page and so

- when people search in Google "words that end with er", Google should
  give `example.com/some-page?ending=er`
- when people search in Google
  "words that end with abc", google should give
  `example.com/some-page?ending=abc`

In general, to tell that page is dynamic and all endings give different content? Should I generate all possible endings?

Comment: Do you have a list of endings that people are interested in?     It doesn't make sense to submit pages to Google that nobody is ever going to search for.   For example, you don't want to submit your `ending=amically` page, even if you have one.   Nobody would ever search for "Words ending in amically".

Comment: You also have to be careful not to run afoul of [Google's webmaster guideline against automatically generated content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306?hl=en).   Your pages have to give value to searchers above what is out there right now.   Google has cracked down on sites trying to rank for every phone number with automatically generated pages for each.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to *submit* pages like that to Google but, as is pointed out in the comments, it's not at all guaranteed that they will show in the index or benefit you in any way and may even hurt you. What works in your favor is the existence of other "list pages" for searches like `foods that start with x` as well as sites that are used to help solve crossword puzzles.

So long as your endings are limited and somewhat navigable (e.g. a menu of the most common 2-3 letter endings for english words), I don't see why Google would completely ignore it.  What Google probably won't do is enter the `er` into your site's search form and send users to it.